# WSO2 APIM : adding SSL certificate for APIs endpoint using rest service

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying to add SSL certificates for the endpoint of the APIs which are created in the APIM 2.5.0

I am able to add the SSL certificate using keyimport tool from commandline and things are working as expected.
But, is there a possibility to add the certificate using restAPI when we are adding the APIs using restAPIs.

May be in the payload which is generated to add an API in the APIM as stated in the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/RESTful+APIs

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting! I have updated the corresponding WSO2 API Manager release documentation for the [2.2.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Dynamic+SSL+Certificate+Installation), [2.5.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Dynamic+SSL+Certificate+Installation) and [2.6.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Dynamic+SSL+Certificate+Installation) in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Mariangela Hills: Thanks
So in APIM 2.6.0, using rest API, the certificate for backend server of APIs can be added and then server restart is not required any more. my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager has a dynamic SSL certificate installation feature where you can skip manual importing the certificate for the endpoint. This feature is only available in APIM 2.5.0 WUM updated pack and GA pack of APIM 2.6.0. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Dynamic+SSL+Certificate+Installation

In APIM 2.6.0, this feature is enhanced by introducing a REST API for importing certificates. For your endpoints, you can import a certificate. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#CertificatesIndividual#certificatesPost

If you want to use the REST API for importing certs, you have to go with APIM 2.6.0.

Comment: I was going through the options1 where APIM2.5.0 is used. In the documentation, it is mentioned that restart is also required? I am confused, even though adding certificate in client-truststore, we need to restart the server? or it will be updated after 10 mins automatically and restart is not required?

Comment: This feature came into resolve that issue. I think you have got confused with the first sentence in this documentation. The first sentence explains the problem.

Comment: Thanks So in APIM 2.6.0, using rest API, the certificate for backend server of APIs can be added and then server restart is not required any more as the newly added SSL certificate will be reloaded automatically (based on fileintervaltime). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Can you please share some more thoughts on this if possible

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This feature addresses restarting issue